# Compress small strings, with what to create external dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I want to compress much small strings (about 75-100 length c# string).
At the time the dictionary is created I already know all short strings (nearly a trillion). There will no additional short strings in future.
I need to extra exactly one string without decompress other strings.

Now I am looking for a library or the best way to do the following:

1. Create a dictionary using all strings I have
2. Using this dictionary to compress each string
3. a way to compress one string using the dictionary from 1.

I found a [good related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479218/how-to-compress-small-strings), but this is not c# specific. Maybe there is something for c# I do not know, or a fancy library or someone has already done that. That is the reason I ask this question.

EDIT:

With dictionary I am talking about things like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder
But everything helps to get the strings shorter. The strings are short text messages in various languages and URLs (30%/70%). There is no need that the compressed strings is human readable. It will be stored in binary files.

Comment: What type of data is in the strings? (mostly ASCII? Random letters? GUIDs?)

Comment: By dictionary, do you mean the .NET `Dictionary` class that stores key-value pairs? Are the strings going to be used as keys or values in your dictionary? If the strings are only values, what will the keys be?

Comment: mostly ascii, not random. Like short text messages, sentences and urls.

Comment: With dictionary I am referring to the dictionary compression algorithms are creating. For example used by Huffman coding. I am not talking about the .NET Dictionary.

Comment: What will be the key in the dictionary?   Don't follow what you me by 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are a trillion strings and no more, then each can be represented in 40 bits (5 bytes).  All you need is a way to use the 5-bytes as an index to the trillion strings.

How do you know all trillion strings?  If the compressor and decompressor both have access to all trillion strings, or if there is way to order and recreate the strings, then all you need is the index.

If you can't find a way to index the strings, then you can take a subset of the strings and use them as a dictionary for a compressor.  Just take the most representative sample (you need to figure out what might make some of the strings more common than the other strings or more representative of the other strings) and concatenate them into a 32K dictionary.  About 400 of your trillion strings.  Then zlib's deflateSetDictionary on the compress end and inflateSetDictionary on the decompress end, both using exactly the same 32K dictionary.  That will provide good compression on the short strings.

Comment: The first one is not applicable in special domain. But the second one (deflateSetDictionary) sounds very promising. I have one question regardings the dictionaries: Let's say I have in my Dictionary the following values: "CDEFGHIJK" and "ABC" and others. When I compress the string "ABCDEFGHIJK" will it use the value "ABC" and then not "CDEFGHIJK" from my dictionary, or will it not use "ABC" but it will use "CDEFGHIJK" (what would be better)?

Comment: One additional question: You wrote I should use 400 of my trillion strings. Is 32K the size of the dictionary or the value count? As it seems it is a byte array will null terminated strings, having the most probable string at the end.

Comment: deflate will find and use the longer string to match.  That is generally better.  If you know which strings might be more common, you should put those at the end of the dictionary, and the less common at start.  (This results in fewer bits on average for the coding of the distances.)  32K is the size of the dictionary.  So 400 strings is just a rough estimate from your "75-100" as to how many will fit.

Comment: If your strings are always zero-terminated, then you don't need to send the zero, and you don't need to put the zeros in the dictionary.  Deflate is a self-terminating format.  You can send just the string without the terminating zero, and add the terminating zero back after decompression.

Comment: But then Deflate does not know when a string ends? When I have "ABC" and "DEF" and I write in the dictionary "ABCDEF" I will just enter one zero byte between both. When creating the dictionary, should I use at least two byte sequences as entries or would very common one byte characters also be useful (for example "a", "e")? Currently I am scanning all texts for 12 char values, then 11 char values and so on. Then I get the number of occurrences. "a" and "e" are more often than for example "Hello". I also plan to repeat this procedure starting at position two for every string.

Comment: Deflate doesn't need to know where the strings end.  All it's looking for is the longest matching string.  A lack of terminating null increases the chances of matches.  E.g. if you have an ABC string and a DEF string, and they are in the dictionary as ABCDEF, then if there happens to be an BCDE in the data being compressed, then that match is available in the dictionary.  The minimum length for a match is three, so common single bytes or pairs of bytes don't matter.

Comment: Most relevant part of answer, IMOHO: "take a subset of the strings and use them as a dictionary for a compressor" .. now one just needs to find a [deflate] implementation that exposes such. DeflateStream in .NET does not :(

Comment: @user2864740  There is nothing to expose.

Comment: @MarkAdler Then "use them as a dictionary for a compressor" is not possible, as the common dictionary cannot be shared across compressing/decompressing individual (discreet) strings / sections of data.

Comment: Yes it can. Comments are not for extended discussions (even though that's what these look like). If you want to know more, you should ask a new question.

Comment: "Then zlib's deflateSetDictionary on the compress end and inflateSetDictionary on the decompress end, both using exactly the same 32K dictionary." - so how is this possible to do (efficiently) in .NET's DeflateStream?

Comment: It isn't. Those zlib functions are not exposed in the .NET class.

Comment: That was my initial compl^H^Hment.. answer is good, I'm just bummed I can't use that bit ^_^

Comment: You could compile zlib yourself and link it to your program.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but [Smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) sounds promising for this...

> Smaz is a simple compression library suitable for compressing very
>   short strings. General purpose compression libraries will build the
>   state needed for compressing data dynamically, in order to be able to
>   compress every kind of data. This is a very good idea, but not for a
>   specific problem: compressing small strings will not work.
>
> Smaz instead is not good for compressing general purpose data, but can
>   compress text by 40-50% in the average case (works better with
>   English), and is able to perform a bit of compression for HTML and
>   urls as well. The important point is that Smaz is able to compress
>   even strings of two or three bytes!
>
> For example the string "the" is compressed into a single byte.

Since it's written in C, check out [Bart De Smet's example for interoping with C through C#](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/01/24/3799.aspx).

Comment: If they are short text strings of a known language; smaz sounds ideal; it will compress short common verbs (the,that,he,she,it,I,etc) into very short byte sequences. If the strings lose that pattern, you may even end up seeing that your compressed strings are longer!

Comment: You could try to translate it, or use interop (see my updated answer).